# How to write Pandoc filter to remove a body text

Tags: filter, pandoc

I have a large set of notes written in Pandoc markdown that I would like the option to convert into beamer slides where only the headers, lists, tables, and equations survive. So I would like to remove all of the plain text. (I know that this doesn't make for *great* presentations, but it is a start.)

I thought the following would work, but I don't understand the pandocfilter objects.

I use the following command line.

```
pandoc -t beamer -o filter.pdf --filter=.\filter.bat --slide-level=2 filter.md
```

Where filter.bat is a wrapper to make the script executable.

```
python filter.py %*
```

And filter.py is a simple script.

```
"""
Pandoc filter to remove text, but leave headers, equations, and lists
"""

from pandocfilters import toJSONFilter, Str, Para

def noText(key, value, format, meta):
  if key == 'Para':
    return Para([Str ""])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  toJSONFilter(noText)
```

And filter.md is a simple pandoc markdown file.

```
---
title: Testing Filters
author: Richard Herron
---

# One

Weathered 3D-printed shoes faded post-bicycle man smart-render-farm soul-delay pre-crypto-network table papier-mache. Geodesic fetishism futurity table refrigerator silent boat industrial grade decay euro-pop. Paranoid vinyl shanty town Tokyo long-chain hydrocarbons sprawl drone pistol office DIY hotdog nano-footage. Math-spook shrine monofilament decay dome meta-rifle soul-delay corrupted fetishism cardboard artisanal carbon denim human table. 

## Two

Kowloon tattoo euro-pop tube ablative tiger-team voodoo god digital bomb man bicycle vinyl monofilament papier-mache A.I. San Francisco. Cartel Shibuya alcohol stimulate vehicle wonton soup camera dissident order-flow boat systemic concrete pre-vinyl. Range-rover spook tiger-team computer singularity Shibuya convenience store urban tower smart-dolphin bicycle skyscraper carbon tank-traps systemic. Long-chain hydrocarbons assault vehicle motion carbon girl sentient systemic otaku rifle dead realism. Free-market franchise Chiba 3D-printed beef noodles meta-grenade construct rebar. 

- One
- Two
- Three

## Two B

Franchise spook sprawl network lights Tokyo plastic grenade. Corrupted systemic paranoid singularity semiotics shoes numinous military-grade kanji j-pop. Modem table bicycle-space market corporation tattoo advert car youtube soul-delay. Euro-pop grenade rifle long-chain hydrocarbons ablative media neon bridge courier 8-bit physical savant advert boy neural tanto.
```

But I get the following error.

```
  File "filter.py", line 9
    return Para([Str ""])
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am on Windows. Can I only use filters on *nix?

Comment: I think it's just a matter of syntax. `return Para([Str("")])` should work

Comment: @scoa Thanks! You're right. But now i'm back to where I was with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696797/how-to-use-python-filter-with-pandoc-to-convert-md-with-tikz-to-html-on-windows) and keep getting the `pandoc: Failed reading: satisfyElem
` error. I think that Windows and pandoc filters don't mix, so I'm getting a Linux to get this to work. Thanks!